# Serve static files from Java webapp on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm a bit lost here and I should know this by now, but I don't. I have exclusively been working with backend Java by exposing REST-services. Now I want to include a file, such as an *.html file, in my project that anyone should be able to access using https. I have included a file in my project root and I have added:

```
<resource-files>
    <include path="/**.html" />
</resource-files>
```

in my appengine-web.xml. Then I deploy it on

```
https://myhostingdomain.appspot.com/thenameofthefile.html
```

This does not work. I've also tried going into servlet mapping in web.xml and map url pattern to *.html but no luck so far. Any advice regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this file into /war folder. Then it should be accessible from the Internet.

Also, if you want this file to be the default page (e.g. displayed when a user visits your domain without specifying the page), you can add this to your web.xml file (for example):

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I am using a maven webapp archetype as template for my project. Where should I have this war folder in my project, in the root?

Comment: Your project should already have a /war folder. It's automatically created. If you don't see it, check the output folder in your build path configuration.